# I need a SQL query to fetch last attribute value from an XML element

Tags: xml-parsing, sqlxml

I need a SQL query to fetch last attribute value from an XML element. I have XML as shown in below. I need to fetch Name value that is 'Current State Contracting' from legalNames/Name Path. any help on this is appreciated..

```
<legalNames id="l5922F64208E14D97BEE4C2E94B670146" deleted="0">
  <operatingNames id="o370FA0A9EAE54290B132211A1EB28D8D" deleted="0">
    <Name>CSR Contracting</Name>
  </operatingNames>
  <Name prior="" id="N45BF84B89B4F4DB987C07EF568E585D9">Current State Contracting</Name>
</legalNames>
```

Comment: My answer was a bit to fast, as you do not state which RDBMS you are using. Please tag your question with the appropriate product and version!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sorry for the delayed response, I actually found a solution for it.
Using (.) instead of column will solve the problem like this ('(.)[1]', 'varchar(500)'). below was my exact code to get all the values from LegalNames/Name path.

```
SELECT HistoryID,
    x.r.value('(@id)[1]', 'varchar(500)') AS  NameID,
    x.r.value('(@prior)[1]', 'varchar(500)') AS  Name_prior,
    x.r.value('(.)[1]', 'varchar(500)') AS  Name    
From 
    (select  HistoryID,XMLData
     FROM [Compass Source_Test].dbo.Temp_History_table_july11) s 
     CROSS apply  s.XMLData.nodes('legalNames/Name') as  x(r)
```

Comment: HI, great that you found a solution on your own! But please allow me one hint: This answer is of absolutely no help for anybody trying to find a solution for a related problem. Your `('(.)[1]', 'varchar(500)')` will pick the *first occurance of the current node*, which is rather - uhm - meaningless... Try to include a minimal working example (you might copy from my answer) to demonstrate your solution  And please tag your question with the RDBMS you are using. Happy coding!

Comment: Hi once again, thx for adding the code! To help you for future questions: In  your question you did not state, that this is coming from a table - quite a difference. Your approach with `.nodes()` navigates to the actual element which make your calls to `.value()` possible. This is only meaningfull, if you you want to fetch several values from the same position. Again something you did not state in your question. Your answer covers a different issue actually... And btw: Your code should work without the `()[1]` too. Happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

Try it like this (SQL-Server syntax):

```
DECLARE @xml XML=
'<legalNames id="l5922F64208E14D97BEE4C2E94B670146" deleted="0">
  <operatingNames id="o370FA0A9EAE54290B132211A1EB28D8D" deleted="0">
    <Name>CSR Contracting</Name>
  </operatingNames>
  <Name prior="" id="N45BF84B89B4F4DB987C07EF568E585D9">Current State Contracting</Name>
</legalNames>';

select @xml.value('(/legalNames/Name)[1]','nvarchar(max)')
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply Shnugo.